# Eclipse C++ - output to window DOS

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am using Eclipse with C++. When I run the program, I get the following message in my Console window:
**** Build of configuration Debug for project Disks Repulsion ****
**** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
Nothing to build for Disks Repulsion

I makes changes to the program and run it again, and this time I get following message:
**** Build of configuration Debug for project Disks Repulsion ****
**** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
g++ -oDisksRepulsion.exe DisksRepulsion.o -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lglut32
C:\MinGW\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5........\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: cannot open output file DisksRepulsion.exe: Permission denied
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Build error occurred, build is stopped
Time consumed: 103  ms.

When I first ran the program, it started my program (I can see it running in my Window Task Manager), but there is no output being sent to the console.
After making changes to my program, the program is still running in the background, so I get the "Permission denied" error, when I try to run the program. I can make the error go away by ending the instances via task manager. However, when I run the program, I still don't see any output being sent to the console. 
Yesterday, I was able to see the output in my console, but don't know why I cannot see it today. Also, when I saw my output, the cursor's focus did not change from the code to the console. I dislike having to  do it manually.

I also don't like that when I make changes to my program, and run it again, that the program is not automatically terminated on its own.

I have used VC++ and I prefer the window Dos for output. So, I wanted to know if there is anyway in Eclipse to send the output to Windows Command Prompt, since I know that the instance of the .exe is really gone when I close the program. It automatically gets cursor's focus. I will also be able to get some output.

I installed MinGW with MaSYS or something, to compile the program.

Comment: What about stopping it from eclipse, by pressing red "terminate" button in eclipse console of the running program? Also that button being disabled means program has exited.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your application isn't terminating on its own and you didn't build in any sort of interface that would allow you to kill the program.  This sounds like a bug in your code and not an Eclipse issue.  If issuing a Ctrl+C in the console won't kill your program, then look into coding something that will let you kill your app with keystroke or input sequence.

If you want to run your app in a command console, then open a normal command console, browse to the folder containing your project, and run the compiled executable from the console instead of doing it through the Eclipse interface.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution, which I've been using for ages now, is opening a command prompt yourself and running the executable manually. An advantage of this method is that you can set your "DOS" window's size to anything you want. (Right now I'm using a 120x50 window with 8192 lines of scrollback buffer.) Another one is that you will never lose your console output; in fact, you'll be able to see outputs from past runs. (8192 lines is A LOT unless you're printf-debugging a tight loop.)

An alternative to terminating your program from the taskbar is using the red icons on the top right corner of the Eclipse "Console" window.

Answer (score 0):

Is your program's entrypoint main() or WinMain()?  There may also be a setting/link option for the "subsystem," console or Windows I think they're called in Visual Studio.

Anyway, if your program is starting up via WinMain, the expectation is that you'll have a Windows form of some sort through which the user can control the program.  If you use main(), then your program should automatically trigger the opening of a console window.

Look up AllocConsole() on MSDN (or google it) if you are using WinMain() intentionally and want a console window to also open up.  There's some trickery also available via google search that can hook stdout to this console, but at this time I don't remember what it is.  (You basically redirect the stdout handle to your new console.)

Good luck.